# Chart on Telerik Report: erratic behavior in datetime line graph

Tags: charts, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am trying to render a telerik report graph. This graph can have up to 5 different series, though most have 3. I have a odd problem where one (or more of the lines) does not perform as expected and behaves erratically. When I checked the objects, the data appears to be correct.

Any Ideas?

[image: Charting Error]
[image: Charting Error]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the points need to be ordered while entering them via C#. If they are entered out of order then you get the above behavior.